# Visa issued of my NzETA travelling with Spanish passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, new-zealand, eta, spanish-citizens

I will travel with my Spanish passport. I already have issued my NZeTA authorization to travel to Auckland.

I travel to Santiago de Chile with Copa airline ticket and the next day I travel by Lan Chile Latam air ticket from Santiago de Chile to Auckland.

The only thing I need is to have printed my NZeta visa issued? How can I recheck that my visa Nzeta is correct with my information in the passport?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the visa verification service, from the [NZ GOV website](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/check-your-visas-conditions):

> ## Check online
>
> To check your visa conditions online you need to register and log in to our Visa Verification Service and enter your personal and visa details listed below:
>
> - family name
> - passport nationality
> - current passport number
> - date of birth
> - gender
> - visa start date

This service is provided by RealMe. You can create an account using the link [here](https://www2.logon.realme.govt.nz/cls/register/createlogon/createlogon?cid=1), or logging in [here](https://www2.logon.realme.govt.nz/cls/logon.logon?cid=3).

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing I need is to have printed my NZeta visa issued?

You do not need to printout of your NZeTA, although you may wish to retain a printout for your comfort.  LATAM will verify your NZeTA electronically against your passport when you check in at Santiago, using the the Government's [Advance Passenger Processing](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/assist-migrants-and-students/other-industry-partners/airlines) system.  Therefore it is important that you check into your flight to New Zealand using the same passport as the one you used when you applied for your NZeTA.

> How can I recheck that my visa Nzeta is correct with my information in the passport?

Use the [NZeTA status check](https://nzeta.immigration.govt.nz/check-status).